# TextMate - Alternate Parenthesis Color?

Tags: textmate

Does anyone know how to do this? Or is it possible? It would make spotting mismatched parenthesis quite nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextMate can't do it as is.

It may be possible, though, but I think you'd need to edit languages definitions for that.